# Get the Key of the highest Value in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Given a hashmap (or a "Dictionary") as a JavaScript object, I'd like to get the Key who has the maximum Value - assuming all Values are integers.

In case there's more than one, I don't care which one of them.

Considering

```
var b = { '1': 9, '2': 7, '3': 7, '4': 9, '5': 3 };
```

I can extract the desired Key by:

```
parseInt(_(b).chain().pairs().max(function(p){return p[1];}).value()[0])
```

which returns `1`.

How can this be achieved more elegantly?

I tried with `_.invert` as well but couldn't make it look better.

Comment: It looks like you're seeking the *key* with the largest *value*. Note that the keys are strings while the values are integers.

Comment: You're right, my apologies. I modified my question, but this still does not answer.

Comment: There's something ambiguous here, since there are 2 keys with a value of 9: `b['1']` and `b['4']`. You say you want the "first" key (`'1'`), but JS objects are technically unordered, so you could get the `'4'` key instead. So do you want the lowest key with the highest value, or simply any key with the highest value?

Comment: "In case there's more than one, I don't care which one of them." - so I want simply any key with the highest value.

Comment: Sorry - completely overlooked that line

Comment: If you use `parseInt`, you should always specify a base: `parseInt(…, 10)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I found what I was looking for. Thanks anyway for all help.

```
parseInt( _(b).invert()[_(b).max()] )
```

This returns 4, which is just good as 1 according to requirements. It looks more elegant and it is way shorter than the pairing stuff.

Comment: This returns the max *value*, but the question asked how to get the *key* of the max value. Not a big deal, though. :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about elegant, but you can omit the initial `_()`, use `+` to convert to number instead of `parseInt` and just pull out the iterator.

```
var iterator = function(p){return p[1];}
var maxKey = +_.chain(b).pairs().max(iterator).value()[0];
// Removed the | 0 since the keys are integers to begin with
```

Here's an alternate way to do it using ES5 `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Object.keys`. You can also use underscore's `_.reduce` and `_.keys` for compatibility. Note that this runs through the entire array, so any duplicates found will use the latest value.

```
var max = Object.keys(b).reduce(function(max,key){
  return (max === undefined || b[key] > b[max]) ? +key : max;
});
```

Making it more clear what we're doing, in case you aren't familiar of reduce, is to use `Array.prototype.forEach` (or `_.each`):

```
var max;
Object.keys(b).forEach(function(key){
  max = (b[key] > b[max]) ? +key : max;
});
```

Comment: I think `| 0` is an anti-pattern as it is completely unclear what it's doing to anyone who hasn't seen it before. What's wrong with `parseInt`?

Comment: I have to agree with @IngoBürk, `|0` may be good if you're trying to Golf the code, but here we seek readability... However, I loved the idea of using an iterator function rather than using an anoynmous function. I just hoped someone will enlighten me, supplying a completely different approch for this task, avoiding the pairing and un-pairing etc.

Comment: @IngoBürk most of this underscore stuff should be completely unclear to anyone who hasn't seen it before. Does that make it an antipattern also?

Comment: @user40171 "here we seek readability" ... just looking at your line of code from the POV of someone who didn't write it, is it obvious that it is meant to return the key of the highest value in an object's properties? IOW is it really that readable to you? I usually find these densely-packed functional sorts of snippets to be difficult to read at a glance after they're written, sort of like regex. I think I'd be able to discern the purpose of an eqivalent `for` loop much faster. I'm curious what others think, though.

Comment: You're missing `typeof` for `max === 'undefined'` and the final expression will not find a key if all values are negative. Use `var max = null` and `max === null || ...`

Comment: Actually, won't returning a key from the `reduce` function make it the next `max` value? You need to return the new max value after storing the key.

Comment: @Dagg If I know `_`, I can read that. But if I know Javascript, `| 0` is nothing that *speaks* to me. It's code that doesn't reveal its intention intuitively and that I consider code smell. I do agree that either way, this behavior should be encapsulated into a function abstracting the implementation away, but my original question stands: What is the argument against `parseInt`? We – luckily – don't live in a world anymore where a few bytes matter, certainly not in a world where they matter more than readability of code.

Comment: @IngoBürk if you know JavaScript, don't you know how its bitwise operators work?  If you know JavaScript, haven't you seen the `n | 0` idiom countless times? Why doesn't it "speak" to you? I don't think it makes sense to say something is an antipattern because someone who looks at it might not be familiar with it. 

I don't have a problem with `parseInt` other than people always forgetting it doesn't default to base 10. In this case, I do question the need to do typecasting at all, but without seeing more than one line of code it's pretty impossible to review that.

Comment: The idea of `+` and `| 0` should be familiar to any intermediate JS developer, which the OP does seem to be one. Also, a simple "What does `+` do in JS" or "What does `| 0` in JS" isn't that much of a hassle.

Comment: @Dagg Even knowing what it means, coming across it you have to internally translate the meaning of it. Given that there is a perfectly readable alternative that reveals its intention much clearer, I fail to see the argument *against* using it. If one feels that `parseInt` still isn't expressive enough, they can encapsulate it (or `| 0`) into a well-named function. But from an abstraction point of view I find it disturbing in the reading flow to come across `| 0`. It's a detail that is completely irrelevant on this level of abstraction and `parseInt` just already offers abstraction.

Answer (score 3):

The way I would do this with the current iteration of `underscore` (1.6) would be through reduce. *Note use `_.reduceRight` if you want to favour items to the left*

```
_.reduce(b, function(max, current, key) {
    return max && max.value > current ? max : {
        value: current,
        key: key
    };
}).key
```

However, in `lodash` you can use `findKey` which would be more intuitive. `_.findKey` will be available in underscore 2.0 if they accept my pull request [`#1587`](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/pull/1587)

```
var maxValue = _.max(b);
_.findKey(b, function(x) {
    return x === maxValue;
});
```